# cy.origin throws error when trying to call a function which has the args's variable as a parameter

Tags: cypress

```
     cy.visit('somesite1.com');
      ....
      ....
      const args = {
        testObject: myObject
      };

      cy.origin( 'somesite2.com', { args  }, ({testObject}) => {
      console.log('print  out my  test obj', testObject);
      someFunction(testObject);}
```

`

I am trying to use the cross domain feature. I have Cypress 10.3.1. I am able to visit the cross domain  but I have trouble passing the variable for further testing. The error I see is

```
ReferenceError
_actions4 is not defined

Variables must either be defined within the cy.origin() command or passed in using the args option.
```

myObject is a json object.
Can someone help please?
Krithika

Comment: Where are you getting someFunction?

Comment: Do you have any function or variabled called `_actions4`?

Comment: I am getting someFunction from a different file which I am importing @TesterDick.
No. I do not have _actions4 variable CaíqueCoelho